# remove lines after pattern in multiple files

Tags: regex, perl, unix, grep, exec

I have the following command

```
find ./ -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's/<pattern>//g' '{}' \;
```

it works well and remove the pattern, but how can I remove the pattern, the line it is on, and `n` lines after?

Comment: Can pattern exist more than twice in each file? Do you want to replace only 2 instances?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Perl but with `find`: if you are using _GNU find_ then you can write
`find ./ -type f -exec perl … '{}' +` instead of `find ./ -type f -exec perl … '{}' \;`. Note the `+` instead of the `\;`.
`find` will then call `perl` with multiple filenames at once (as many as fit into the command line) and thus dramatically decrease the overall execution time.

Comment: @PerlDog Thank you. It did improve it significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more brute force than elegant, but I think this will remove the line with the matching pattern and the line following it.

```
find ./ -type f -exec perl -i -e '$x=0 ; while (<>) {if ($_ =~ /<pattern>/) { $x++; next; }; if ($x) { $x=0; next; }; print "$_";}' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks! I do want to remove the following 4 lines though, so how do I do that? I assume I need to change `next` to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Take a file :

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
```

Now, we want to remove from `bbb` to `ccc`, so :

```
perl -i -0pe 's/bbb.*ccc//ms'  file
```

The `0` will *slurp* the file paragraph by paragraph

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution, but I am looking for something that would work for multiple files at once.

Comment: So add this `perl` cmd to your original find maybe ?!

Comment: It removes only the first part of the line in both cases. So if it were `s/aaabbbeee.*eeecccfff//ms`, it would leave the `eee` and `fff` and put them into one line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perl answer for just one file.  I don't want anyone who finds this question to not realize the `find` which you have wrapped it in will edit hidden files as well.

**Answer:**

`perl -ni -e '$ml=$. if /<pattern>/; print unless (defined $ml && $.<=$ml+[n])' input-file`

**Explanation:**

`perl -ni` will read and replace the `input-file` but only print if instructed to

`$ml=$. if /<pattern>/` sets the `$ml` matching line variable to `$.`, which is the current line of the input file

`print unless (defined $ml && $.<=$ml+[n])` will print every line except the the line that matches and the [n] next lines

Comment: @Nik to answer your question on the other answer, the solution to remove the line and the next 4 is: `find ./ -type f -exec perl -ni -e '$ml=$. if /<pattern>/; print unless (defined $ml && $.<=$ml+4)' {} +`